# Why isn't $\int_0^1{1/x^2}~dx= 1$ + the integral from 1 to infinity.

Tags: integration, paradoxes

This probably as nearly a stupid question as the one that isn't asked, 
but I've always thought the area under the curve is equal to the integral.
So 
Given the function $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ which is symetric about $y = x$,
why isn't the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ of $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ equal to
the $\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{x^2}\,dx$ minus $1$ The unit square under integrated area.
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\dfrac{1}{x^2}\,dx &= 1 - 0 = 1
& \text{and}&&
\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{x^2}\,dx &= \infty - 1 =\infty
\end{align}
At least when using the Reimann improper integral.
I also tried Lebesgue and got the same answers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: The function isn't symmetric with respect to $x=y$. The part on $(0,1)$ is symmetric to $1/\sqrt{x}$ by reflection in $x = y$.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out just after I posted, thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This site has a feature called MathJax that let's you format proper mathematics using keyboard characters.  I'll try my hand at editing your Question, but if you learn to use this, it may help you think the problem through as you carefully explain the formulas involved.

Comment: Thanks for that, I didnt think to use the dollar dollar syntax, but Im aware of it now.

Answer (score 0):

There is an isometry between the domain $D$ bounded by the curve $y=1/x$ for $x$ in $(0,1]$, the segment $[0,1]\times\{1\}$ and the halfline $\{0\}\times[1,+\infty)$, and the domain $E$ bounded by the curve $y=1/x$ for $x$ in $[1,+\infty)$, the segment $\{1\}\times[0,1]$ and the halfline $[1,+\infty)\times\{0\}$.

But the area of $E$ is $\int\limits_1^\infty\frac1{x}\mathrm dx=+\infty$. On the other hand, consider the square $K=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, then $K$ and $D$ are disjoint and the area of $K\cup D$ is $\int\limits_0^1\frac1{x}\mathrm dx=+\infty$.

Thus, if one insists on translating the isometry between $D$ and $E$ in terms of areas, one should write something like $+\infty=+\infty-1$... which, despite some uneasy feelings the RHS may bring to the reader, happens to be true.